# UITextField textFieldDidBeginEditing: Not called on the first selection

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I'm trying to set up an action that happens immediately when a UITextField starts editing (changing some text to help the user with what to put in the field in an external view that slides in)

I've included the UITextFieldDelegate in my View Controller, and implemented the textFieldDidBeginEditing: method, however this method seems to only be called after the first time the UITextField is selected (it doesn't get called the first time).

Is there any reason this is happening which can be prevented, or is there a better way to do this? (i.e. check which text field is editing when the UIButton is pressed).

The help panel (helpPanel) is loaded in the viewDidLoad: method.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == tfMyTextField) {
        [helpPanel setTextTitle:@"'Title'"];
        [helpPanel setText:@"'message'"];
    } 
}

-(IBAction)showHelp:(id)sender {
    [self dismissAllInputs];
    SidePanelController *side = (SidePanelController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController;
    [side showLeftPanelAnimated:YES]; // the left panel is the helpPanel instance
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code? How (and when) are you making this help panel slide out? The "delay" you mention sounds like no more than the delay caused by the rise of the keyboard.

Comment: Added - the SidePanelController is an implementation of an external library which allows for panels. The left panel which gets shown is simply my instance of helpPanel, and is set in the viewDidLoad: method

Comment: Thanks for showing that. So what's the problem? It looks like you're successfully setting the title and text of the `helpPanel`, yes?

Comment: Managed to narrow down the issue. The text does not update when the UITextField is selected the first time. Subsequent selections of the UITextField update the text fine- I'll update the question

Comment: How is the UITextField selected? Is it always because the user taps in it?

Comment: Yes - the view loads with no keyboard etc, but the users presses the UITextField to start editing

Comment: Please add logging to `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and confirm that `helpPanel` even exists yet. I don't know anything about this third-party library but it sounds to me like you're missing a step that creates the `helpPanel`. If it doesn't exist there is nothing to set.

Comment: Also your title is now misleading. Are you really claiming that `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is not called???? That's very unlikely. Unless you've forgotten to set the text field's delegate until later. Please use logging and / or breakpoints to confirm this. "seems to only be called" - DO NOT GUESS. There is no "seems" in programming. It is called or it is not called.

Comment: Added logging, it is in fact called (and identified as the correct text field too) so it's an issue with setting the text. I've checked that the helpPanel is initialised by adding logging to viewDidLoad:. It's fully initialised before the setText methods are used. It appears that if you try to set text before the helpPanel has appeared, it doesn't update. Can't see a reason for this though

Comment: I told you, I don't know this third-party library. But they perhaps don't create the panel until the first time you summon it. That would be quite natural.

Comment: The library is JASidePanelController. As far as I'm aware, since I instantiate the helpPanel myself (using the storyboard), the view should have loaded. The library just holds a reference to it. I've even called viewDidLoad: on helpPanel after creation and that hasn't worked. I'm wondering whether storyboard connections aren't made until after the view has appeared (which would explain why the text doesn't update)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a simple matter of the order in which things happen. Consider this code:

```
if (textField == tfMyTextField) {
    [helpPanel setTextTitle:@"'Title'"];
    [helpPanel setText:@"'message'"];
}
```

You are assuming that `helpPanel` already exists and can be updated. But if it hasn't appeared yet, perhaps it doesn't exist yet.

So instead, try this: do not set the `helpPanel` title and text until *after* you call `[side showLeftPanelAnimated:YES]`.

Comment: Thanks Matt - followed your advice, and changed the way I've done the message update. I've made two NSString's to hold both variables which are updated when the UITextField starts editing, then after "showLeftPanelAnimated:" is called, I've done the setText: setTextTitle: methods there, referencing to the strings. Thanks again :)

Comment: That is exactly what I was going to suggest!!!!!! Well done.